# data frame by date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, iteration

I have a dataframe and its head looks like this:

| DATE | Symbol | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-06 | CEZ | 40 |
| 2021-02-08 | KB | 30 |
| 2021-02-09 | CEZ | 70 |
| 2021-02-11 | KB | 50 |
| 2021-02-12 | CEZ | 100 |

And I want to iterate through the data frame and for each day from 2021-02-06 to Sys.date() capture the last value for each Symbol so it would look like this:

| DATE | CEZ | KB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-06 | 40 | 0 |
| 2021-02-07 | 40 | 30 |
| 2021-02-08 | 40 | 30 |
| 2021-02-09 | 70 | 30 |
| 2021-02-10 | 70 | 30 |
| 2021-02-11 | 70 | 50 |
| 2021-02-12 | 100 | 50 |

I tried something like this:

```
for (day in seq(from=as.Date('2020-03-02'), to=Sys.Date(),by='days')) {
    data.frame %>%
      group_by(Symbol) %>%
      filter(DATE < day)%>%
      Here Im lost, how to create the desired table and do that for each day. 
}
```

The data.frame that Im working with is much more complicated, this is just minimal examle. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to use `dcast` from `data.table` (or `reshape2`)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.frame %>% as.data.table()  # data frame to data table
dcast(dt[!duplicated(dt, by = c("DATE","Symbol"), fromLast = T) & # removing not last appearance
           as.Date(DATE) <= Sys.Date()],  # removing dates from future
      DATE ~ Symbol , # rows ~ cols
      value.var = 'VALUE', # val
      fill = 0 # to fill NAs if needed
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in wide format, use `complete` to fill the date sequence from minimum date to today's date and `fill` the `NA` values with the previous values for all the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Symbol, values_from = VALUE) %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.Date(DATE)) %>%
  complete(DATE = seq(min(DATE), Sys.Date(), 'day')) %>%
  fill(-DATE) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

#   DATE         CEZ    KB
#   <date>     <int> <int>
# 1 2021-02-06    40     0
# 2 2021-02-07    40     0
# 3 2021-02-08    40    30
# 4 2021-02-09    70    30
# 5 2021-02-10    70    30
# 6 2021-02-11    70    50
# 7 2021-02-12   100    50
# 8 2021-02-13   100    50
# 9 2021-02-14   100    50
#10 2021-02-15   100    50
# … with 164 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = c("2021-02-06", "2021-02-08", "2021-02-09", 
"2021-02-11", "2021-02-12"), Symbol = c("CEZ", "KB", "CEZ", "KB", 
"CEZ"), VALUE = c(40L, 30L, 70L, 50L, 100L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That is unfortunately too complicated for me. But thank you for your help anyways.